# Facing Type Problem with CLIPS 6.3 IDE editor?

Tags: clips, expert-system

After typing 4 alphabets, It won't appear the next typing alphabets. Please have a look the attached screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWzBv.png)

After I typed the "haii" word, the next alphabet that I typed won't appear.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Which CLIPS IDE are you using?

Comment: The CLIPS 6.3 IDE for Windows uses the Win32 APIs and that limits the amount of text you can enter to 32K.